# Watch-kit : adding "Notifications Scene" to existing watchkit app ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, watchkit, xcode7.2

- I have created an iOS app then i added new Watch-kit app target 
  without notifications scene.
- Previously i did not need to show    notifications.But now i want to
  add notifications scene also.i want    to add **"Notifications
  Scene"** in my existing Watch-kit app.
- Will i    have to create new target ? or i will have to add
  notifications    classes and interface file manually?

I have searched on SO and other
   developers forums , i did not get any satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you do not have to create another target to handle notifications. All you need to do is to add the `Notification Interface Controller` object to your `Interface.stroyboard` file plus a `.apns` file you need to create which would have been created by Xcode if you have selected the option during project creation.

Add a `Notification Interface Controller` object from object library and select the option `Has Dynamic Interfaces` if you are implementing a dynamic notification scene. This will add another scene automatically to your stroyboard.

Check the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html) for details and Tutorial to set up remote notification in Watch App. Though the tutorial doesn't add the notification scene separately but you will get the idea [https://www.natashatherobot.com/watchkit-actionable-notifications](https://www.natashatherobot.com/watchkit-actionable-notifications/)